# Таблица результатов Winforms

Tags: c#, winforms

Подскажите пожалуйста, как в конструкторе Visual Studio можно сделать такую таблицу и добавлять в неё результаты работы программы?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А что конкретно не понятно? Постройте подобную форму в конструкторе WinForms, и наполняйте её из кода, или же записывайте сначала в лог файл. Все данные можно спокойно получить

Comment: STALKER, а как сделать саму таблицу?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

По поводу таблицы - DatagridView(объект) у WinForms. Заполнять его можно по разному, создать объект-источник, заполнить его и потом привязать к таблице(один из вариантов). По поводу привода примера кода - не вижу пока что в этом смысла.